# What are my options to reframe the bottom of this basement wall?

Tags: basement, framing, basement-refinishing

I just had interior draintile installed. The bottom of this ledge-wall (not sure what it's called) was framed with a floor plate and intermittent studs. They got removed during the concrete work.

I need to reattach the paneling.

Do I reframe like it was, with floor plate and studs?

Could/should I instead anchor pressure treated 2x4s to the walls, without a floor plate?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Place "sill plate gasket" between bottom plate and concrete, and use untreated 2x4 for framing as you see convenient.

The gasket is not required if the bottom plate sits on the tile.

The wall space will be kept dry because it breathes to the living space.

Anchor single-bottom plate to concrete with concrete screws. If anchoring to floor is problematic, affix bottom plate flat against wall instead, allowing studs to bare on the 1.5in edge of such plate.

This is not structural, so do whatever works and keeps the walls and finishing stable under normal lateral forces like people or furniture leaning against it.